# unable to Mock repository using MockitoExtension

Tags: java, mockito

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EmployeeRepositorySinkTest {

    EmployeeRepositorySink repoSink;

    @Mock
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        repoSink = new EmployeeRepositorySink(employeeRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSink() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId("Id-123");

    //call by a akka stream
    verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).saveAndFlush(argThat(trd -> trd.getId() == "Id-123"));
  }
```

When I run the unit test case first time it runs , when I run second time it fails, is there some issue with Mockito mocking

```
employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(
    <Employee repository sink test$$ lambda$ 5 2 4/ 0x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 5b 7 4 4 0>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.employee.EmployeeRepositorySinkTest.testSink(EmployeeRepositorySinkTest.java:65)
But was 0 times.

org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooLittleActualInvocations: 
employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(
    <Employee repository sink test$$ lambda$ 5 2 4/ 0x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 5b 7 4 4 0>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.employee,EmployeeRepositorySinkTest.testSink(EmployeeRepositorySinkTest.java:65)
But was 0 times.`
```

Comment: Are you comparing Strings with `==`? Not that it's related to your problem (or maybe it is), but it's an amateur level mistake.

Comment: Please share complete error log

Comment: @Smile added error message

Comment: IMHO the error is here:`//call by a akka stream`. You can try with `verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).saveAndFlush(any()));` or similar

Comment: problem is if I run the test case first time it succeeds second time it fails

Comment: when i renamed the vatiable of employeeRepositorySInk to employeeRepositorySink1 it succeeded then again it failed on seconds time.looks some issue with mocking